# React: XX is not a function - but it is and it works with other components

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, react-functional-component

I have the problem that I cannot pass a value to a function as a prop since it is not recognized as a function - but it clearly is. Let me show you my code.

**Highest Component - Treelist**

```
export const TreeList = ( {  treeData, updateSelectedNodeId }) => {

    function updateOfSelectedNode(nodeId) {
        updateSelectedNodeId(nodeId);
    }
  
    return (
        <>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col text-center">
            <h2>Tree Visualization component</h2>
              <div className="row mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-lg-8 text-left text-dark">
                    {/* <Tree treeData= { treeData } logg = { logger } /> */}
                    <Tree
                    treeData = { treeData }
                    currentNodeIdUpdate = { updateOfSelectedNode }
                    >
                    </Tree>


                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Next Component - the tree**

```
export const Tree = ( { treeData, currentNodeIdUpdate }) => {

    // const [currentNodeId, setCurrentNodeId] = useState();

    function updateSelectedNodeHandler(nodeId) {
        console.log(`tree : request to approve update of nodeId is : ${nodeId}`);
        console.log(currentNodeIdUpdate);
        currentNodeIdUpdate(nodeId)
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <div className="d-tree">
                <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column tree-connect">
                    { treeData.map(tree => (
                        <TreeNode node={ tree } updateSelectedNodeId = { updateSelectedNodeHandler  }></TreeNode>
                    ))}
                </ul>

            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Smalles Component - Treenode**

```
export const TreeNode = ( { node, updateSelectedNodeId }) => {
    const [childVisible, setChildVisiblity] = useState(false);


    const hasChild = node.children.length > 0 ? true : false;

    const changeVisibility = () => {
        setChildVisiblity( (v) => !v);
    }

    function updateSelectedNode(nodeId) {
        console.log(`update of node id happened: currently at ${nodeId}`);
        updateSelectedNodeId(nodeId);
    }



    return (
        <div className="testA">
        <li className="d-tree-node border-0">
            <div className="d-flex" onClick={changeVisibility}>
                {hasChild && (
                    <div className={`d-inline d-tree-toggler ${childVisible ? "active" : ""}`}>
                    </div>
                )}
                <div className="col d-tree-head">
                    {node.limitGroupName &&
                    <div className="node-tree-card"  onClick={() => updateSelectedNode(node.limitGroupId)}>
                        <p>{node.limitGroupName}</p>
                    </div>
                    }
                    
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* {hasChild && childVisible && ( */}
            {true && true && (
                <div className="d-flex d-tree-content">
                    <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column tree-connect">
                        <Tree treeData={node.children} />
                    </ul>
                </div>
                )
            }
        </li>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see I am using always functions and pass them as props from the highest component (Treelist) to the lowest component (treenode). If a Treenode is selected, I want to pass the ID of the respective node back to the highest component.

However, if I try to test this, I get the error that  **currentNodeIdUpdate** in **Tree** is not a function. However, it clearly is, as you can see in TreeList.

What am I missing?
Sitting for hours on this problem...

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `TreeNode` component you're rendering the `Tree`

```
<Tree treeData={node.children} />
```

But the `Tree` component requires second prop named `currentNodeIdUpdate` which should be function.

In this case, it's undefined;

If you add a check in the `Tree` component it should fix the issue.

Something like:

```
function updateSelectedNodeHandler(nodeId) {
    console.log(`tree : request to approve update of nodeId is : ${nodeId}`);
    console.log(currentNodeIdUpdate);

    if(currentNodeIdUpdate) {
      currentNodeIdUpdate(nodeId)
    }
};
```